# Como selecionar o resultado de um json CEP em um option existente?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.getJSON(url, function(json){

    $("#pf_endereco").val(json.logradouro);
    $("#pf_bairro").val(json.bairro);
    $("#cidade").val(json.localidade); <----
    $("#estado").val(json.uf); <----
```

Como colocar as informações de **localidade** e **uf** conforme mostra estas setas (`<----`) dentro de um formulário quando ele é do tipo `select > option`?

> **Atualização**

```
json.localidade - "MS"
json.localidade - "Campo Grande"

<option value=""></option>
<option value="000001">AC</option>
<option value="000002">AL</option>
<option value="000003">AM</option>
<option value="000004">AP</option>
```

> **Atualização 2**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Aqui tem possíveis métodos. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740195/adding-options-to-a-select-using-jquery-javascript

Comment: Você quer criar novos options ou marcar um existente como selecionado?

Comment: Marcar um existente como selecionado !!!

Comment: Como são os `value`s dos seus options? E o que vem em json.localidade e .uf?

Comment: `bfavaretto` atualizei a pergunta com as duas informações - o retorno e os options.

Comment: O ideal seria retornar `000001` etc em json.uf, em vez de `MS`. E o equivalente para a cidade.

Comment: Infelizmente é um script externo e retorna os dados dessa forma. Provavelmente ter que selecionar pelo `text` !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você não tem como alterar o que vem no JSON para bater com os seus `value`s, você precisa de um seletor que olhe o conteúdo dos options, e não seu valor:

```
$("#estado option:contains('" + json.uf + "')").prop('selected', true);
$("#cidade option:contains('" + json.localidade + "')").prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: Retornando onde?

Comment: Mas é pra ser um objeto mesmo. (dica: use `console.log` em vez de alert, e **sempre abra o console do seu browser**). O que tem em `$("#estado option:contains('" + json.uf + "')").length`?

Comment: Pelas informações retornadas na **Atualização 2** acho que só está tendo um problema na seleção dos campos porque está retornando os dados necessários.

Comment: Tente `$('#estado').val($("option:contains('" + json.uf + "')").val())`

Comment: Não !!! http://encomenda.axitech.com.br/sys/cadastro

Comment: use o que está na minha resposta e depois `$('#estado').trigger("chosen:updated");`. Você não tem um select normal, está usando um plugin chamado *chosen*.